# How to get a Image from web url without lossing its properties in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i am downloading an image from url from my application using http post method. after that how to save that with out losing its properties like transference?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you save an image to the device:

```
try {
    FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(filePath,Connector.READ_WRITE);
    fconn.create();
    out = fconn.openOutputStream();
    out.write(yourImageBytes);
    out.flush();
    fconn.close();
} catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: thank you,i am getting that data from web in bytes. then how can i save without losing its properties

Comment: Farid Farhat gave a nice answer. So it's unclear what do you mean in "how can i save without losing its properties". That's a nonsense.